# jQuery validate with custom checkbox CSS not working after form validation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, jquery-validate

I am using these custom CSS checkboxes on a form, but noticed after I submit the form (which then runs jQuery validate), the custom checkbox does not show anymore. The checkbox behavior still "works", it's just the checkbox is no longer styled in the custom way.

I've put together a fiddle showing this: https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/z31q59hc/8/

Also, I'll include the code here.

You can see that at default, the checkbox works great, when checked and unchecked. The moment that you submit the form, then the checkbox no longer is styled (but, it still "works", just not blue background with the custom styled checkmark anymore).

Any advice on how best to "fix" this would be awesome.

thanks!

HTML

```
<form id="addressForm" name="addressForm" method="post">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="alertBox infoAlert" style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:4px;">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label class="checkboxContainer">I have read and agree to the Privacy Policy
        <input type="checkbox" name="privacyPolicyCheckbox" id="privacyPolicyCheckbox" value="no">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.alertBox -->
</div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:20px;"><input type="submit" value="Go to Next Screen" class="btn btn-cta-ecommerce fullWidthButton760" id="addressFormSubmit" style="min-width:350px;" /></div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
 /* Customize the label (the container) */
.checkboxContainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
 /* margin-bottom: 12px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;/* was 22px */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.checkboxContainer input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;/* was 0 */
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;/* was #eee */
  border: 1px solid #333;/* added */
 }
 /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
 .checkboxContainer:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;/* was #ccc */
  }
 /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
 .checkboxContainer input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
 }
 /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
 }
/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.checkboxContainer input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}
/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
 .checkboxContainer .checkmark:after {
 left: 10px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 6px;
   height: 11px;
   border: solid white;
   border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JS

```
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "help-block",
        highlight: function(element) {
            jQuery(element).parent().is('.has-success, .has-error') ?
                jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error') :
                jQuery(element).wrap('<span class="has-error"></span>');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            jQuery(element).parent().is('.has-success, .has-error') ?
                jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success') :
                jQuery(element).wrap('<span class="has-success"></span>');
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "nonMemberType") //not needed on this screen, but keeping placeholder syntax
                error.insertAfter("#selectNonMemberValidationBlock"); //not needed, see above
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    jQuery("#addressForm").validate({
        rules: {
            'privacyPolicyCheckbox': {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            'privacyPolicyCheckbox': {
                required: "Please indicate that you agree to the Terms and Conditions by checking this box."
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on jsfiddle...

Comment: Hi @Alessio - I am not sure why not... Basically, the checkbox first works checked and unchecked. Then, press the submit button. Then, the checkbox is no longer styled (checked). It still will toggle the jQuery validate message (showing it's adding/removing the .has-error and .has-success codes), but, the checkbox is no longer styled after initiating the jQuery validate.

Comment: Hi @gamehendge, the problem is that when I press the button, the form is sent and JSfiddle or Codepen kind of crash...so I cannot see the broken checkbox...

Comment: Hi @Alessio - I see what you mean, but the form doesn't always submit in the jFiddle... you can still trigger the jQuery validate which is preventing it from submitting, then see the behavior... There's isn't an "action" on the form, and I tried changing it to get instead of post, but that didn't work (do you know how I can alter the form code to not allow the 404 page?). But again, if you first check, then uncheck, then submit, then you will be "stuck" with the form validation working, which will prevent the submit, and you can see the "no styles for checkbox anymore" issue, at least with FF

Comment: Absolutely useless jsFiddle.  I've disabled submit via the `submitHandler` so you can see that nothing is even being validated here.  https://jsfiddle.net/ykhn5stv/

Comment: You have to also properly set the `ignore` option to "nothing" in order for any validation to occur, then maybe this is the issue?  https://jsfiddle.net/ykhn5stv/1/

Comment: In order to effectively troubleshoot this problem, you need to inspect the live DOM.  Only then you can see how the CSS is being applied and which class is interfering with the visual representation of the checkmark.

Comment: Hi @Sparky - thanks for the tip about disabling the submit. I updated my original fiddle. I agree with you about inspecting the DOM, that's what I've been trying to do the last few hours and running into a brick wall. That is why I asked for help. It seems to be a conflict with the custom checkbox styling (CSS) and the jQuery validation markup that appears when the form is submitted (.has-error and .has-success), but that is where I'm stuck. I've tried z-indexes, positions, etc. But just can't seem to see why the jQuery validate, when run, makes the custom checkbox styling disappear.

Comment: It shouldn't.  All the plugin is doing by default is adding/removing classes from the `input` elements and toggling the visibility of the error.  Since you added custom `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions, start there because these override the defaults.  Obviously, there is a CSS property that is part of the plugin's valid/invalid class that is negating a CSS property of the class that creates the checkmark.

Comment: Hi @Sparky - you are correct, after I removed the custom highlight part of the JS, then the checkbox continued to work after the jQuery validate was run... I guess I just have to see now what that affects (this field is actually part of a screen which is part of say 10 others using the same code)... Or, find a way to have the custom highlight/unhighlight wraps place nicely with the custom checkbox styling code... thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: No reason to remove custom `highlight` and `unhighlight`.  And if you have one, you should have the other... they complement each other.  See posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
highlight: function(element) {
    jQuery(element).parent().is('.has-success, .has-error') ?
        jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error') :
        jQuery(element).wrap('<span class="has-error"></span>'); // <- ???
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    jQuery(element).parent().is('.has-success, .has-error') ?
        jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success') :
        jQuery(element).wrap('<span class="has-success"></span>'); // <- ???
},
```

I don't think you should be dynamically "wrapping" anything in a `span` element based on validation pass/fail.  It doesn't make sense.  All that should be happening with `highlight` and `unhighlight` is adding/removing classes.

By invoking `.wrap('<span.../>')` you are altering the structure of the DOM, thereby breaking any jQuery DOM traversal code that affects where/how the checkbox is constructed.

The if/then/else conditional logic doesn't even make a lot of sense here because both functions are testing for existence of the same classes.

By removing the conditional logic, thereby removing the `.wrap()`, your problem goes away.

```
highlight: function(element) {
    jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
},
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/wdecm1u5/](https://jsfiddle.net/wdecm1u5/)**

Comment: thanks, again, Sparky... I appreciate your help and guidance... marked as accepted answer ;-)